# Como crear copia de miembro privado de una clase para ser leido por otra clase en c++

Tags: c++, class

Tengo una clase cuyo metodo createEdges() crea una matriz de aristas  que representan un grafo: int**iEdges. Quero que iEdges pueda ser accedido por un metodo de otra clase con fines de lectura. ¿Como puedo garantizar que iEdges solo pueda ser leido y evitar que pueda ser modificado en la segunda clase?
De acuerdo al codigo que muestro a continuacion me gustaría escuchar sugerencias respecto a la mejor forma de conseguir lo anterior. Varias soluciones me han pasado por la cabeza como usar herencia, amistad, crear una segunda matriz y copiar cada valor de iEdges en un loop anidado, o bien converir iEdges en  un miembro publico. Pero debe haber una mejor forma de lograrlo. Aqui el codigo:

```
class Edges{
    private:
    int edgesLen;
    int**iEdges; // miembro que quiero que sea leido por la clase Graph
    public:
        Edges(int len){
            edgesLen = len;
            iEdges = new  int*[len];
             for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
                iEdges[x] = new  int[2];
             }
        }

    public:
//llena la matriz con valores del usuario
        void createEdges(){
            printf("lets create the edges array \n");
            for(int i = 0; i < edgesLen; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    printf("give the value of edges at position %i %i \n", i, j);
                    scanf("%i", &iEdges[i][j]);
                }
            }

        }
        
  //una vez lleno con valores, iEdges debe ser leido por la clase Graph.
  // funcionParaDevolverIdges(){}

};
class Graph: public AdjacencyList{
    protected:
        int** matrix;
        int numberNodes;
    public:
        Graph(int numberNodes) : AdjacencyList(numberNodes){
            this->numberNodes = numberNodes;
            printf("this is number nodes: %i \n", numberNodes);
             matrix = new int*[numberNodes];
             for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++) {
                matrix[i] = new int[numberNodes];
             }
            for(int x = 0; x < numberNodes; x++ ){
                for(int y = 0; y < numberNodes; y++ ){
                    matrix[x][y] = 0;
                }
            }
           
        }



        //Aqui es donde leo iEdges. 
          int** edgesArrayToMatrix(int** edges, int edgesLen){

            //fill the matrix with 1s at the positions whith  intersections
            
          }

          
          


};
```

Comment: La garantía de que no vas a modificar un parámetro es marcandolo como `const`. `const int** edges`. De forma similar con los métodos de una instancia. Si no van a modificar la instancia, las funciones tienen que estar marcadas como const.

Comment: El problema es que usando "const" tengo que inicializar iEdges y no puedo modificar su valor inicial. Sin embargo los valores de iEdges vienen de un input de usuario por tanto: 1. no tengo valores iniciales. 2Quiero modificarlo a lo largo del programa dentro de la clase Edges. Sin embargo, una vez fuera de la clase Edges, ya no quiero que iEdges se pueda modificar.

Comment: Me refiero al parámetro de la función `edgesArray...`. no necesitas que el miembro de `Edge` lo sea.

Comment: Propones que edgesArrayToMatrix espere un parametro de tipo const int** , correcto? No obstante,  recuerda que iEdges es declarado como int** en la clase Edges, por tanto el complilador arrojaria el error: "cannot convert int** to cont int**".  Si no me equivoco. En otras palabras, el tipo de dato de iEdges tiene que ser el mismo que el tipo de dato que espera recibir edgesArrayToMatrix().

Comment: Ok, veo que [no ocurre conversión implícita](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5055655/13419694), pero si puedes usar una conversión explícita.